# how to insert company with branches and vice-versa

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have Model Company and the company can be a branch
so lets say Company A is a Branch of Company B and vice-versa

In the database table I have something like this

companies

```
id name
1 Company A
2 Company B
3 Company C
```

company_branches

```
company_id branch_id
1 2
1 3
```

My problem is if I want to know the branches of company A then no problem but what I want is if I want to know the branches of company B I should have A and C

I dont know what relation I should have and how the insertion and updating will be

Comment: Company B doesn't have any branches in your example. Company B only has a parent company which is A.

Comment: the problem is in the system theres no parent company, they all child, if you assign from one child his brothers then you can reach all the brothers from any child

Comment: which db? don't say mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think parent-child relation will work here as well like in category listing.

What I did was create a table where

> id | name | parent_id

If the category items were parent, the parent_id would be 0 while in other case, it would be the respective id of the parent item.

> 1 | A | 0 
>   2 | B | 1

Here A is parent item and B is child item of A. This will be the table storing the items in database. 
For their retrieval in orderly manner, I used this recursive function :

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
$tree = $this->buildTree($rows);
print_r( $tree );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is theres no parent, they all childs and siblings

Comment: This is what I knew. I am sorry if that didn't help.